# Hiding the toolbar

Tags: objective-c

I am doing application using ios 4.0. I need to hide UIToolbar when I go from second view to firstview. As secondview consists UIToolbar. In secondView I am having `NavigationBarButton` I wrote the code as below.

```
-(void)back
{
     [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So, I am able to hide when I am coming from firstview to secondview but the problem is when I am in secondview if I click on home button and again if run the application then its starts from secondview as I stoped there. Now, if I pop to firstview I am getting toolbar. I am not getting what's the reason and problem.

Can any one help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this when hiding toolbar?

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```